# SharePoint Licensing Issue

Tags: internet

I am going crazy on the license problem as the Sales told me our existing solution cannot be allowed the let the external client to access our SharePoint site....

we have purchased

1 x SharePoint Standard 2010 Server License
20 x SharePoint CALs
I have setup a Windows AD with 15 users / purchased 20 x Windows CALs in a Virtual Machine
I have purchased a SQL2008 R2 per processor/per server (I knew this version is for unlimited Client access and no need to purchase CAL) and installed to another Virtual Machine.
The two VMs are housed in a VMWare Exsi 5.1 Server

I put it on a external network apart from our Company LAN and client can access our sharepoint site using http://mycompany.com/SPClientSite (they need to enter the pre-set AD user name and password in order to access the content).

The sales told me we need to purchase the NEW SharePoint 2013 server + CALs / MS Server 2012 Server + Cal in order not to violate the Microsoft licensing scheme..

Is there any cheapest way to comply with Microsoft licensing scheme with my company environment ... ????

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to buy SharePoint 2013 to comply with any licensing issues?

Currently your setup is like so:

- SharePoint Server 2010
- 15 SharePoint User CALs
- SQL Server 2008 R2

Given that you have appropriate Windows Server licenses, you can now run one SharePoint server with one SQL Server as the database backend.

No matter how your 15 SharePoint users (which you have licensed) access this SharePoint, they are allowed to do so. You are asking about *"client can access"* which I could assume to mean these clients are **not** one of your SharePoint users, correct?

With SharePoint 2010 you will **need one CAL for each named user**. In your case: For each Active Directory account accessing your SharePoint, you will need a CAL.

There is one other license model which is called *SharePoint for Internet Sites*. For a lump sum you allow **any number of external users** to access your SharePoint that way. External users means anyone outside of your company and not affiliated with it.

With **SharePoint 2013 this licensing model changed**: By buying the SharePoint Server license, you allow any number of external users (again not affiliated with you, no onsite contracts) to access your SharePoint. You still need one CAL per internal user. If you have many outside contractors, affiliated companies it might be cheaper to switch to SharePoint 2013 as your sales guy has suggested. The User CALs are more expensive now, but you don't have any cost for external users anymore.

Answer (score 0):

MoonTear you forget about external connectors for windows. :)
If you want to login users from internet.
You should have to buy Sharepoint for internet Sites(Sharepoint 2010), Windows Server License, External Connectors License for Windows.

In my situation I can say that Sharepoint for Internet Sites is 4 time more expensive then for Intranet Sites.

So the best is to buy new Sharepoint 2013 license as Moontear suggest.